# System.Data.Entity.DbSet cannot be called with instance of type System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error when trying to call the list method

Additional information: Method 'GRCWebApp.Models.Day Find(System.Object[])' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[GRCWebApp.Models.Day]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[GRCWebApp.Models.Day]'

The Controller is

```
        public ActionResult ListClubMembershipType(int clubId)
    {
        //Populate the list
        var types = from s in db.MembershipTypes
                    where (s.ClubId == clubId)
                    orderby s.Type
                    select s;
        ViewBag.typesCount = types.Count();
        var model = types.Select(t => new ListMembershipTypeViewModel            
    {
        Type = t.Type,
        ClubId = clubId,
        Cost = t.Cost,
        ReducedCost = t.ReducedCost,
        ReducedDate = db.Days.Find(t.DayId).DayNum + "/" + db.Months.Find(t.MonthId).MonthName,
        MinAge = t.MinAge,
        MaxAge = t.MaxAge,
    });

        return PartialView("_ListClubMembershipType", model);
    }
```

and the error is on the ReducedDate line

The Day Model is:

```
public class Day
{
    public int DayId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int DayNum { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The Month Model is:

```
    public class Month
{
    public int MonthId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public String MonthName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The MembershipType Model is:

```
        public int MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public String Type { get; set; }

    [StringLength(350)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
    public Decimal ReducedCost { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int? DayId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int? MonthId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int MinAge { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool? Dormant { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel Is:

```
    public class ListMembershipTypeViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public String Type { get; set; }

    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Cost")]
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Reduced Cost")]
    public Decimal ReducedCost { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Reduced From")]
    public string ReducedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Min Age")]
    public int MinAge { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Max Age")]
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to combine the values from two other table to make up a string that shows the day number and the month word

Ive tried adding the ToString but that generates the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding Day and Month to the MembershipType Model

```
    public Day Day { get; set; }

    public Month Month { get; set; }
```

Then the following in the controller:

```
ReducedDate = t.Day.DayNum + " " + t.Month.MonthName,
```

As pointed out in this question [Populating List with related information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231799/populating-list-with-related-information/31231975#31231975)