# Populating List with related information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Have a list view that is populated using this controller:

```
        public ActionResult ListClubMembershipType(int clubId)
    {
        //Populate the list
        var types = from s in db.MembershipTypes
                    where (s.ClubId == clubId)
                    orderby s.Type
                    select s;
        ViewBag.typesCount = types.Count();
        var model = types.Select(t => new ListMembershipTypeViewModel            
    {
        Type = t.Type,
        ClubId = clubId,
        Cost = t.Cost,
        ReducedCost = t.ReducedCost,
        MinAge = t.MinAge,
        MaxAge = t.MaxAge,
    });

        return PartialView("_ListClubMembershipType", model);
    }
```

I would also like to populate a variable in the view model called ReducedDate with data pulled from two other tables, Day & Month.

Ive tried the following line:

```
            ReducedDate = db.Days.Find(t.DayId).DayNum + "/" + db.Months.Find(t.MonthId).MonthName,
```

but it gives the following error:

Additional information: Method 'GRCWebApp.Models.Day Find(System.Object[])' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet1[GRCWebApp.Models.Day]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery1[GRCWebApp.Models.Day]'

What is the correct way to reference the data?

The Models are:

MembershipType

```
public int MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

[StringLength(150)]
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
public String Type { get; set; }

[StringLength(350)]
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
public String Description { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public int ClubId { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
public Decimal Cost { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
public Decimal ReducedCost { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public int? DayId { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public int? MonthId { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public int MinAge { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public int MaxAge { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "bit")]
public bool? Dormant { get; set; }
}
```

The Day Model:

```
public class Day
{
public int DayId { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public int DayNum { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The Month Model:

```
    public class Month
{
public int MonthId { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
public String MonthName { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And the ViewModel is:

```
    public class ListMembershipTypeViewModel
{
[Display(Name = "Type")]
public String Type { get; set; }

public int ClubId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Full Cost")]
public Decimal Cost { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Reduced Cost")]
public Decimal ReducedCost { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Reduced From")]
public string ReducedDate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Min Age")]
public int MinAge { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Max Age")]
public int MaxAge { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `DayId` and `MonthId` on your `MembershipType` but you don't have properties of `public Day Day {get;set;}` and `public Month Month {get;set;}`

If you had those properties you could just use `ReducedDate = t.Day.DayNum + "/" + t.Month.MonthName`

This might give you an error since `DayNum` is an int so you'll need to convert `DayNum` to a `string`.  You can use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t.Day.DayNum)` to do this.